# Ubuntu loads wrong icons theme and fonts

Tags: nautilus, themes, icons, fonts, gtk

Sometimes ubuntu loads default icon theme instead of Faenza icons and fonts look weird:

[image]

But when I do

> setsid unity

Icons are fixed
and when I do

> nautilus -q

Fonts are fixed
Where is problem? How to repair this?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when replaced my HDD (hard disk drive) with SSD (solid state drive). Fonts started looking just like in your pictures! I solved this by disabling the Ubuntu user auto-login in a system. When I switch my laptop, I have to enter password to see desktop but fonts and themes are now looking correct.

Comment: This occurs to me with SSD if I enter my password immediately and quickly. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Some days ago I installed the latest kernel (4.14.15) manually, and that seems fixed.